# How to change text using jQuery onload on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently use this jQuery Code:

```
   if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $mehranzeigen = $('.mehranzeigen');
      if ( $mehranzeigen.text() == 'Hier klicken für mehr Informationen' )    
        $mehranzeigen.text('Mehr Informationen');  
        });
    };
```

but It doesn't work / changes the text on mobile.

**What I need to do?**

I need to change a text inside a button (on devices with less than 768px width) from: `Hier klicken für mehr Informationen` to `Mehr Informationen`

this text is in a button with the css class: `.mehranzeigen`

this should happen onload, as I also change the text onclick with this code:

```
  if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
   $('.mehranzeigen').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('mehranzeigen');
        if($this.hasClass('mehranzeigen')){
            $this.text('Mehr Informationen');           
        } else {
            $this.text('Weniger Informationen');
        }
    })};

  if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
    $('.mehranzeigen').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('mehranzeigen');
        if($this.hasClass('mehranzeigen')){
            $this.text('Hier klicken für mehr Informationen');          
        } else {
            $this.text('Hier klicken für weniger Informationen');
        }
    })};
```

Comment: You should do this with CSS media queries and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it'll be better and easier to create a function for this

```
function ChangeText( screen , element , itext , elsetext){
   var $this = $(element);
   switch(screen){
      case "notdesktop" :
          if($(window).width() < 768){
             if($(element).hasClass("mehranzeigen")){
                $this.text(itext);
             }else{
                $this.text(elsetext);
             }
          }
          break;
      case default :
          if($(window).width() > 768){
             if($this.hasClass("mehranzeigen")){
                $this.text(itext);
             }else{
                $this.text(elsetext);
             }
          }
          break;
   }
}
```

then you can use this function say on `document load`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ChangeText( 'desktop', '.your_reference_class_here', 'Hier klicken für mehr Informationen' , 'Hier klicken für weniger Informationen');
   ChangeText( 'notdesktop', '.your_reference_class_here', 'Mehr Informationen' , 'Weniger Informationen');
});
```

And about click event put the `window width` inside the click not outside BUT it doesn't make sense to use the class to toggle the same class .. anyway the click event should be like

```
$('.your_reference_class_here').on('click' , function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('mehranzeigen');
    ChangeText( 'desktop', $this , 'Hier klicken für mehr Informationen' , 'Hier klicken für weniger Informationen');
    ChangeText( 'notdesktop', $this , 'Mehr Informationen' , 'Weniger Informationen');
});
```

> **Note:** `your_reference_class_here` should be like `class="your_reference_class_here mehranzeigen"`

Finally if you need to use the same thing on window resize you can use

```
$(window).on('resize' , function(){
   ChangeText( 'desktop', '.mehranzeigen', 'Hier klicken für mehr Informationen' , 'Hier klicken für weniger Informationen');
   ChangeText( 'notdesktop', '.mehranzeigen', 'Mehr Informationen' , 'Weniger Informationen');
});
```

This code not tested but I believe you may stuck if you have more than one element with class `mehranzeigen` for this you may need to use `.each()` on load and on resize

```
$('.your_reference_class_here').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    ChangeText( 'desktop', $this , 'Hier klicken für mehr Informationen' , 'Hier klicken für weniger Informationen');
    ChangeText( 'notdesktop', $this , 'Mehr Informationen' , 'Weniger Informationen');
});
```